# $POST is returning empty values from HTML form

Tags: php, html

I am newbie for HTML and PHP programming.
When i am submitting data from form $POST is not fetching values from form and simply empty values are getting mailed .spent quite a lot time for this but couldn't figured it out..

following is part of a code of my HTML Form

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" action="sendemail.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="namefirst" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="emailfirst" class="form-control" placeholder="Email ID">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

following is my PHP code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for registering wth us.We will keep updating you.'
);

{
$name = $_POST["namefirst"]; 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["emailfirst"])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = '****';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" ;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
}

?>
```

i have tried all the possible solutions,but its just not working.Please let me know what is wrong with this.

Comment: Looks like your code has syntax errors. Note sure what `{` is supposed to do without an if statement or something.

Comment: Post your actual code please.  This can't possibly run correctly.

Comment: Suppressing errors `@` isn't really going to help you troubleshoot it either..

Comment: Hi, try to see if the values are set before you set them as variable. Give your submit button a name and start your check with that Eg: if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){ if(isset($_POST['namefirst']) && !empty($_POST['namefirst'])){ $name = $_POST['namefirst']; }}

Comment: @Qirel can you please explain more

Comment: When you've got `@` in front of a line, any errors this line produces will not be reported. Remove those, and enable error-reporting with [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) (put these at the top of your file, after `<?php`) - perhaps that'd shed some light on what we're dealing with.

Comment: Isnt headers are used when submitting a data?

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out ..problem is not with PHP or HTML file it is with javascript code,values were not getting set there @MueyiwaMosesIkomi thanks alot becoz of this i got this problem so to solve this I did following thing:
EARLIER my code was:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {'use strict',
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

which was not sending values. after this code its working;

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
  var namefirst= $('.contact-form' . 'namefirst').val();
 form.submit(function () {'use strict',
    $this = $(this);
          $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
          $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

now its sending values but it is going on next page and showing php echo as it is,not encoding Json so i thnik

```
$this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
```

this part of code is not working...can anyone help regarding this??????

Thanks all of you